# Should I use not-British word meanings in the FCE?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, british-english

This year I will sit the FCE, a British English exam. I don't know if I should use word meanings that aren't in British vocabulary but are common in other countries.

For instance, the word "grouse". In informal Australian English, it's a synonym for "good, excellent", which is great. However, in the Cambridge Dictionary (British English), it means "to complain" or "a fat bird that is hunted or its meat".

What do you think? Thanks.

Comment: When I did my FCE I tried to use "normal English words", did not really think about if they are American English or British or other ones. Having said that, FCE is literally "First" certificate in English. I don't feel trying to achieve your first certificate is the right place to flex with your one Australian slang word. You will impress no-one and you can even embarrass yourself.  Stay humble, even if you excel, your achievement would be only that you can speak the same language as the other 360 million people on the planet. And most of them will not be impressed.

Comment: Where did you hear about "grouse" being used to mean "good or excellent"? As an Australian, I've never heard it used that way; it's possible that it's slang that's limited to one or two cities, or that it's archaic slang that's no longer used. I'm familiar with the "to complain" meaning though, and I've heard of birds called grouses even if they don't live here.

Comment: @nick012000 - Also Australian and have definitely heard grouse used to mean good or excellent in Sydney and westwards. Mostly (always?) ironically as it is an older and very out of fashion slang.

Answer (score 27):

FCE is a test of standard and formal English, suitable for academic or business use. It also tests your ability to use less formal English, for example in a letter to a friend or a magazine article.

You should not be using language that is inappropriate to this context. This means that slang need not be used. British slang: *The daft bloke was totally plastered* would be equally inappropriate to an academic context to Australian and American slang, and not recognising the different registers and dialects in English is a weakness that can lose you marks.

So, no, "grouse" should not be used unless you are referring to the gamebird.

Comment: Erm this is just not the case. FCE tests users formal and ***informal*** English. It is not purely a test of academic and business English either. Candidates may have to write informal letters (where they will be **penalised** for using formal English) and, for example, may encounter informal idioms in the use of English, have to write an article for a magazine (in semi-informal style), or write a story (which will often require very informal style). Please edit so I can upvote you!.

Comment: As a native BrE speaker I am surprised by all the remarks about "grouse" being an uncommon word for "complain". Most people in the UK have probably never seen the bird called a grouse, never eaten one, and certainly never "hunted" one. OTOH "grouse" is a fairly common synonym for "grumble".

Comment: @alephzero As a native BrE speaker... I have most definitely heard of grouses and have never heard it used in the context of grumbling (nor indeed have I heard the AusE meaning)

Comment: @Nick As another, I hear it all the time! Maybe the people you know are too friendly to be grousy!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Nah.... they're just too busy grouching :p

Comment: @Araucaria I was too narrow,  I've edited.  I still feel that you will only need to use appropriate langauage and you won't be tested on words like "grouse"=excellent or "plastered"=drunk

Comment: @Nick https://www.bbc.com/news/av/world-us-canada-50132023 It sounds more familiar to me (AmE) in past tense... "so-and-so groused"... Although once I started looking it showed up in more places ("you guys can grouse all you want").

Comment: @JamesK They certainly won't test you on those, no! But I reckon you'd get extra marks for using "plastered" in the right context in either a magazine article or a story! I think very regional-specific language like *grouse*=excellent is definitely a bad idea. I don't think many British or American FCE examiners would be familiar with t and would just regard it as a mistake!

Comment: I don't think the question is about formal vs. informal (e.g. slang) language. It seems more about dialect: should he avoid using Australian word meanings?

Comment: @Barmar, if you can point me to dialect forms (in australian or otherwise) that are considered part of the high register formal language in that dialect, we can discuss these.  However "grouse" is understood as slang (and from my reading, it is limited to SE Australia (Perth people will know it only as something that people in Melbourne say), and slightly dated: its not really something kids say any more.

Comment: "equally inappropriate to an academic context to Australian and American slang" equally inappropriate *in* an academic context *as* Australian and American slang.

Comment: Hmm... Never heard the Australian meaning of "grouse".  But as a Canadian (first 32 years) and American, next, um, several decades, using "grouse" either as "complain" (when used as a verb) or as an often-hunted bird (as a noun) seems perfectly natural (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grouse)

Comment: @Acccumulation  You know I'm not precious about people fixing errors in my grammar. I know its not perfect (!)

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. *common* slang and idioms are welcomed in informal letters/emails and in speech. But never in a formal essay, and even more so a word that's pretty obscure like *grouse*, the likelihood of needing it is probably 0.1%  and of it actually being useful 0.001%

Comment: @Mari-LouA This post originally just said that FCE was an exam of formal academic and business English, which is not true. Of course, every task must be completed with language that is appropriate in style (what is sometimes incorrectly termed "register"). You'll be penalised for using formal language in tasks requiring informal style & vice versa. As I said in an earlier comment, using very regional specific language is not a good idea. If you were to use the verb *grouse* meaning to complain (a fairly common type of meaning that might be required) in a magazine article etc. you'd gain marks.

Answer (score 13):

You would have to look up the marking criteria for the exam, if they are available. But unless you specifically know that it's OK, it seems unwise to use Australian or other non-British colloquialisms in a British English exam.
Are the examiners based in the UK? Most British people would probably be unaware of the meaning of "grouse" in Australia.

Comment: As a speaker of British English I both agree with this answer, and confirm that I am familiar with both the British-English meanings of "grouse", but not the Australian-English meaning.  The "to complain" meaning is rare in British English, but I've heard it used in Indian English.

Comment: thirding the fact that British speakers are generally unaware of the Australian sense. The "complain" sense is unusual here, but I'd certainly understand it. It would seem quite informal for this exam though

Answer (score 4):

"Grouse" is other than *informal*, for the Australian meaning you give.  Outside of its circle of use, it's **virtually unknown**.  Most Brits would only associate it with the well-known game bird.

Therefore it would be inappropriate to use in formal or business English, in Britain.  "Gripe" on the other hand, is *informal*, and well-known.  To gripe (verb) or to have a gripe (noun) would be totally acceptable in a test of informal English as it's in common usage and would be practical for communication.